# for loop in ctree [R]

Tags: r, loops, character

I want to run a decision tree for each variable in my dataframe, so I'm using this:

```
results_cont = list()

for (i in 2:(ncol(DATA)-1)) {
  current_var = colnames(DATA[i])
  current_result = ctree(TARGET ~ current_var, DATA, control = ctrl)
  results_cont[[i]] = current_result
}
```

Where DATA is a dataframe where the first column is the ID and the last column (TARGET) is my binary Target.

I keep getting this error:

```
Error in trafo(data = data, numeric_trafo = numeric_trafo, factor_trafo = factor_trafo,  : 
  data class “character” is not supported
```

But I don't have any character in mi dataframe.

Is there anything wrong with my loop or something else ?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not provide data, I have not tested this, but I believe your problem is the line
`current_result = ctree(TARGET ~ current_var, DATA, control = ctrl)`
This is not working because `current_var` is just a character string. You need to build the formula as a string and then convert it to a formula - like this:

```
current_var = colnames(DATA[i])
FORM = as.formula(paste("TARGET ~ ", current_var))
current_result = ctree(FORM, DATA, control = ctrl)
```